# Expo and release channels...how to recognise dev/prod and a real channel

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm having some troubles with expo release channels.
I'm not expert about React Native and Expo which makes things much more easier :

If I work with my local development environment, the channel will not be set ( which makes sense ).

But also the final release or "production" will not have a channel set,
which makes very unclear how I should recognize 'production' and 'development'.

Then a new complexity level is added if I want to add a channel...like 'staging', which will have instead a channel...

The icing on the cake is that in my deployment system (Circle) I have to build 'development' in a channel ( otherwise NODE_ENV will be "production" )

Did someone figure out how to use channels correctly? :)

basically, I didn't find a solution better than this one:

```js
import { Constants } from 'expo'
const ENV= {production:{},staging:{},development:{}}

// Having fun with channels
const channel = Constants.manifest.releaseChannel;
if (channel === null || channel === undefined || channel === '') {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    return ENV.production;
  }
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    return ENV.development;
  }
}
if (channel === 'staging') {
  return ENV.staging;
}
if (channel === 'development') {
  return ENV.development;
}
return ENV.production;
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing point what are release channels for.

When your app is built with `exp build` it is bind to one release channel (`default` as default).
Later, if you want to do an OTA update, you can just run `exp publish` which will publish your code on the release channel (again: `default` as default).

When you ship a standalone build to your users, you don't want to give them untested code etc via OTA, so you want users to have release channel set to ex. `prod`.

This is completely separated from NODE_ENV and I don't really see a point in tying them.

Comment: Clearly, I'm missing the point :)

Sorry and thank you for your help.

I've never published a real build so I don't really know what will happen :)

So basically you are saying that when I will publish a real production build it will have channel === default? 
( and I guess development === development and staging === staging if I will publish them in right channels)
I guess the issues is that I would like to have a development build but with production parameters.

Comment: You can publish your app with whatever release channel you want ;) You just probably want to not use it for anything else.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting, that `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'` construct makes sense only during bundle build process - bundler would be run with `NODE_ENV` variable set to specific environment.

In `production` environment that would mean, that bundler's built-in minifier would replace all occurrences of `process.env.NODE_ENV` with it's actual value (`production` f.e.), it's how minifier is configured by default in `metro` bundler. F.e:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
   ... some dev-only code, like 'assert(something)' or 'console.log(some debug info)'
}
```

would become

```
if ('production' !== 'production') {
   ... some dev-only code, like 'assert(something)' or 'console.log(some debug info)'
}
```

and then would be further minified to

```
if (false) {
   ... some dev-only code, like 'assert(something)' or 'console.log(some debug info)'
}
```

which then would be completely eliminated from resulting code as the code inside the `if` statement would never be executed anyway.

For example, your code would be treated in dev mode as:

```
if (channel === null || channel === undefined || channel === '') {
  if ('development' === 'production') {
    return ENV.production;
  }
  if ('development' === 'development') {
    return ENV.development;
  }
}

... further simplified to:

if (channel === null || channel === undefined || channel === '') {
    return ENV.development;
}
```

and in prod mode:

```
if (channel === null || channel === undefined || channel === '') {
  if ('production' === 'production') {
    return ENV.production;
  }
  if ('production' === 'development') {
    return ENV.development;
  }
}

... further simplified to:

if (channel === null || channel === undefined || channel === '') {
    return ENV.production;
}
```

---

You should remember, that react-native code runs inside native app on a device, not inside some `Node` instance, so it knows nothing about strictly Node-specific ecosystem/environment variables (though, you can monkey-patch `process.env` with custom values via some libs like `dot-env` etc), it's one of the reasons some Node utils/packages from `npm` can't be used in a react-native apps as-is, as they are Node-specific (`fs` f.e.).

*It's the same as using `process.env.NODE_ENV` variable on a front-end code that is served to the client's browser - there's just no `process` instance available in a browser, and unless your'e using a minifier and configured it to replace `process.env.NODE_ENV` occurrences with some specific values, your code would simply throw undefined variable access error. `Metro` bundler handles this specific usecase for you, but it's worth mentioning anyway, I think.*